# Using our own local linux kernel source code on Yocto Project

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

We need use our customized linux kernel source code on Yocto Project, is it possible to use our kernel source code with tar file and put it on downloads folder, then use SRC_URI = file://xxx.tar.gz on bb file, let tar file to be the kernel source?  if not, how to do this on our own software project development?

BR,
Jack

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Was it your question?

Answer (score 0):

`virtual/kernel` recipes in Yocto are just simple recipes like all recipes.

So, you can set your recipe source to whatever Yocto supports as source type (`git`, `file`, ...)

For your case, you can:

- Host your custom kernel in a local private git server and use `git`
- Use a local kernel compressed source file and use `file`

Comment: You mention that using a local kernel compressed source file and use file, I try to do this, but it isn't work, I put my kernel compressed source file on downloads folder and in linux kernel bb file, I use  SRC_URI = file://xxx.tar.gz, when I sue bitbake virtual/kernel, it will show like  file not found except in dl_dir error, is there any example I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

`SRC_URI = file://xxx.tar.gz` is correct.

You should not put files into the download folder, bitbake will do that when it downloads something. Put it to your source if you use `file://`.

If your file is not found from the default `FILESPATH` you can add extra directories to search using something like `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${COREBASE}/../mysrc:"`.

Use `bitbake -e [recipe]` if you are unsure where the variables point to.